# How to SELECT with WHERE condition 'IN' referring to text?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have 2 tables.

Table_A keeps reference id (id_ref) int as PK.

Table B stores history of the changes by keeping many id_ref in a field as text.
example: 1,2,3 in this text field

How can I select directly using select * from A where id_ref IN (select id_ref from table B)?

Example query as below:

SELECT name
FROM TABLE_A WHERE
id_ref IN (
SELECT id_ref
FROM TABLE_B WHERE id=4097
);

I can use function explode() in PHP to split and get the the individual value. But is there any ways I can directly query without using split function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery:

```
SELECT id_ref FROM TABLE_B WHERE id=4097
```

returns a string which is a comma separated list of integers and can't be used with the operator `IN`.

You need the function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT name 
FROM TABLE_A 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id_ref, (SELECT id_ref FROM TABLE_B WHERE id = 4097));
```

or:

```
SELECT a.name 
FROM TABLE_A a INNER JOIN TABLE_B b
ON FIND_IN_SET(a.id_ref, b.id_ref)
WHERE b.id = 4097;
```

Comment: tqvm. i have tried the find_in_set and it works